# The image does not display Firebase Storage

Tags: android, imageview, firebase-storage

what am I doing wrong? In this code, I load the image into Firebase Storage and then try to display it. But for some reason the display does not work. It loads it to Storage, but does not want to display it. Can Uri not take it right? As for me, for some reason, the red line underlines this line:

```
downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
```

What's wrong here?

```
public class EditProfile extends Fragment{
    private static final int GALLERY_INTENT=2;
    private EditText editProfileName;
    private EditText editProfilePhone;
    private EditText editProfileNick;
    private ImageView image;
    private Uri downloadUrl;
    private Button saveBtn;
    private final int LENGTH = 1000;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public EditProfile() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_profile, container, false);
        image=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_photo);
        user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        editProfileName=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_name);
        editProfilePhone=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_phone);
        saveBtn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_save);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chageProfile();
            }
        });
        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setImage();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    public void setImage(){

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        startActivityForResult(intent,GALLERY_INTENT);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode==RESULT_OK){

            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading");
            progressDialog.show();
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            StorageReference storageReference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
            StorageReference file=storageReference.child(user.getUid()+"/photo.jpg");
            file.putFile(uri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            // Get a URL to the uploaded content
                            downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                            UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                    .setPhotoUri(downloadUrl)
                                    .build();
                            user.updateProfile(profileUpdates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Фото добавлено",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                            // ...
                        }
                    });
        }
        image.setImageURI(user.getPhotoUrl());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi did you resolved your issue? I am having the same problem.